# Appending numbers into a list in reverse

Tags: python

I'm trying to append numbers from num up to 1 into the list in the first tuple but I can't figure out how to do it. I figured out how to do it with a list, but I'm not quite sure how to do it without one. I tried removing the []'s from [i for i in reversed(range(1, num + 1))] but that didn't work.

What I have so far:

```
def put_to_list(num):
    items = ((0, []), (1, []), (2, []))
    items[0][1].append([i for i in reversed(range(1, num + 1))])
    return items[0]
```

with the above code I get:

```
put_to_list(10)
(0, [[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]])
```

Is there a way to do what I did but instead of the brackets, so:

```
>>> put_to_list(10)
(0, [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `list.extend()` instead:

```
items[0][1].extend([i for i in reversed(range(1, num + 1))])
```

You don't even need to use a list comprehension there:

```
items[0][1].extend(reversed(range(1, num + 1)))
```

or move the the `reversed()` call into the list definition, but call `list()` on it:

```
def put_to_list(num):
    items = ((0, list(reversed(range(1, num + 1)))), (1, []), (2, []))
    return items[0]
```

further simplified to:

```
def put_to_list(num):
    return (0, list(reversed(range(1, num + 1)))
```

or even:

```
def put_to_list(num):
    return (0, list(range(num, 0, -1)))
```

Comment: `items[0][1].extend(reversed(range(1, num + 1)))` is even better :P (+1 all the same)

Answer (score 0):

```
def put_to_list(num):
    items = ((0, []), (1, []), (2, []))
    items[0][1].append([i for i in reversed(range(1, num + 1))])  # This line
    return items[0]
```

In the line I have noted you are appending a list to a list. You can use extend and lose the extra brackets which is =what is causing you to create a list and then append that list to `items`.